# jQuery: Risk of not closing tags in constructors

Tags: jquery, html, html-parsing

Is there any reason I would use `$('<div></div>')` instead of `$('<div>')`?

Or `$('<div><b></b></div>')` instead of `$('<div><b>')`?

I like the latter in both cases because it is shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on whether you use a single tag or multiple tags to create the element/elements.

If you use a single tag, jQuery will use the `document.createElement` method to create the element, so it doesn't matter if you use `"<div/>"` or `"<div></div>"`.

If you have several elements, jQuery will create the elements by creating a `div` element and put the HTML code in the `innerHTML` property. To get the browser to parse the HTML code properly, you have to write it according to the HTML version you are using. If you are using XHTML for the page, the HTML code that you use to create elements has to be XHTML also.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery automaticcally closes the tags for you, there is no need to close it yourself.

`$('<div>')` is a perfectly fine thing to do

In that second thing however you are appending the `<b>` i would do:

```
$('<div>',{html: $('<b>')}); // or $('<div>').append($('<b>'))
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/m9wbb/

Comment: I agree with this `$('<div>',{html: $('<b>')})` up to a point... when you start nesting these things 4+ levels deep your eyes start to bleed. But it does feel more OO

Comment: lol so you define it in variables, never said it was the best to do all inline, which is what i did.

Comment: @Neal yeah, this is what I do, but when I'm not adding classes, attributes, etc, I just go str8 `$('<div><b></b></div>')`

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/ADNjv/ it reads more naturally :) less whitespace and brackets !

Comment: @hunter or just do: `$('<div>').append($('<b>'))`

Comment: What I was talking about was something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/m9wbb/2/ ... but now that I look at it, it is very pretty

Comment: Do you think `$('<div>').append($('<b>'))` is necessary for the `b` tag if you aren't going to do anything jQuery-ish on that object?

Comment: @hunter, you mean its **not** pretty?

Comment: @hunter, you most certainly are, orelse what is the point of the b tag?

Answer (score 3):

I've found edge cases in IE where my code was magically fixed by using `$("<div></div>")` instead of `$("<div>")`. I always do this out of paranoia.

I'm sure at some point the jQuery docs specifically said you should close all your tags. This is no longer the case with 1.6 but if your using 1.3.2 or 1.4.2 you may want to close them to be safe.

Although if you look at the source code I would be tempted that for simple tags it is perfectly safe. Do be wary that for complex tags or tags with attributes the source uses `.innerHTML` so I highly recommend you pass in correctly closed tags.

**The source**

```
var rsingleTag = /^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/;

...

// If a single string is passed in and it's a single tag
// just do a createElement and skip the rest
ret = rsingleTag.exec(selector);

if (ret) {
    if (jQuery.isPlainObject(context)) {
        selector = [document.createElement(ret[1])];
        jQuery.fn.attr.call(selector, context, true);

    } else {
        selector = [doc.createElement(ret[1])];
    }

} else {
    ret = jQuery.buildFragment([match[1]], [doc]);
    selector = (ret.cacheable ? jQuery.clone(ret.fragment) : ret.fragment).childNodes;
}
```

In this case with `$("<div>")` you will find that `ret[1]` is "div" so it calls `document.createElement("div")`.

Comment: An example I encountered was: `$('<span class="manip_link" href="#" onClick="return false;">').text('[remove]');`  This did not show up in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.  Turning it into a "self-closing tag" by saying `... false;" />` was one way to make it work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does that for you, but consider writing the correct HTML for better readability (the former in the question) :)