# transform div into h2 span jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a generated title **dynamic title**

```
<div class="title">dynamic content</div>
```

and i would like to transform it like so:

```
<h2 class="title"><span>dynamic content</span></h2>
```

Would that be doable in jQuery?

Comment: Do you only have one such div on your page? Or were you hoping to apply this transformation to multiple titles on the same page, all with `class="title"`?

Comment: only one jQuery('div.title:eq(0)').replaceWith(function() { 
    return jQuery('<h2>').addClass('title ').append(jQuery('<span>').text(jQuery(this).text()));
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$('div.title').replaceWith(function() { 
    return $('<h2>').addClass('title').append($('<span>').text($(this).text()));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uPFUu/

Comment: I like this solution. It is neat using `function` with `replaceWith`. (You will want to add your close parenthesis to the end to make it work)

Comment: Yeah, I like it too. Maybe you want to use html() instead of text(), as hughes did, depending on what you need. But html() is less destructive.

Comment: Yeah, could use html() instead. Does it actually make much difference? (assuming there is no html inside)

Comment: No. But better yet, you could use the append method like I did. That is even less destructive because it (should) also preserve events that were added, but not part of the HTML. But like you said, it does not make a difference.

Comment: That is interesting, I didn't know a function could be put there. Since the function is a single statement, what benefit is there in using a function over just putting that statement as the parameter?

Comment: You can reference $(this) inside the function to refer to the div you are replacing.

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

```
$('.title').replaceWith('<h2 class="title"><span>'+$('.title').html()+'</span></h2>');
```

Comment: You answered a bit fast I think. It won't work for multiples <div class="title">

Comment: This works. Note it only will work properly if either there is only one `.title` or they are all identical.

Comment: Ok, but why be so limited? Plus you run the selector twice.

Comment: I feel it kind of does. Ok the job is done, but this is less reusable, less smart/elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.title').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<h2>').append($('<span>').append($(this).children().remove())))
})
```

Notice my strings `'<h2>'` and `'<span>'`. Only because they are simple tags can I omit the end tags safely. To get your class you will want one of

```
$('div.title').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<h2>').addClass('title').append($('<span>').append($(this).children().remove())))
})
```

or

```
$('div.title').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<h2 class="title"></h2>').append($('<span>').append($(this).children().remove())))
})
```

See [jQuery: Risk of not closing tags in constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941910/jquery-risk-of-not-closing-tags-in-constructors)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.title').html('<span>' + $('.title').html() + '</span>');
```

Comment: This does not replace `div` with `h2` as the OP requested. Also it just would not work. having `htmlstring + jqueryobject + htmlstring`

Comment: oh, didn't even notice that. and it would work, here is a jsfiddle of it. http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/d5QRv/

Comment: You can delete your own answer. That way it will keep things less cluttered. You can post a new answer later or you can just edit this answer.

Comment: You do know that the `htmlstring + jqueryobject + htmlstring` works right?

Comment: I see it has been corrected. Either that or I mis-read it the first time. `htmlstring + jqueryobject + htmlstring`  does not work while this works `htmlstring + jqueryobject.html() + htmlstring` because it is the same as `htmlstring + htmlstring + htmlstring`.

Comment: Oh, I corrected it seconds after I posted it. Your comment wasn't there when the edit was complete; my bad.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/964/discussion-between-phil-and-cjavapro)