# jquery - working backwards

Tags: jquery

I was able to set the focus of a table element by using the following code:

```
document.getElementById($('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+lstRow+')')
        .attr('id')).focus();
```

I was able to verify that the id of the tr is in fact the correct id:

```
console.log($('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+lstRow+')').attr('id'));
```

What I need to do is get the actual HTML of that tr of the id I'm on..

Basically using some variation of this code, I need the html of the tr element:

```
console.log($('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+lstRow+')').attr('id'));
```

But I only need the beginning `<tr>` html.  I don't need the `<td>` or the closing `</tr>`.

```
<table>
  <tr id='123'>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='abc'>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So I would only want the `<tr id='123'>` for example.

Comment: Could you edit your post to surround your code snippets with `, please? We can't see which are the bits you want or don't want! :)

Comment: I'm confused -- what do you mean by the beginning html?

Comment: have you considered the `.prev()` function?

Comment: I thought I did...  Sorry if I didn't.

Comment: @Jeff I recommend verifying your question in the preview view **before** posting the question. (The preview view is right below the box where you input your question.)

Comment: @Sime Vidas - I did...   It looks like people have edited it to correct whatever I left out.

Comment: @Jeff All HTML tags have to be marked as code to be visible (e.g. `<td>`). Watch out for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tr = $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:eq('+lstRow+')')
var html = $('<tbody>').append(tr.clone()).html().replace(/>[\s\S]*/,'>')
console.log(html)
```

**Details**

You cannot directly get the HTML of an element, only the DOM `innerHTML`. (same as jQuery `html()`)

So first we make a new empty `$('<tbody>')`. This does not exist in the document, it is therefore invisible and private to our JavaScript. Nothing else can see it.

We then add a copy of that tr with `.append(tr.clone())`. (We have to copy it first or else we will remove it from the original location during `append`)

Then we get the `innerHTML` of the tbody with `.html()`. We now have the "outer HTML" of the TR (`<tr`...`>`...`</tr>`)

The final step is simple, we need to strip out everything after the first `>`, so I use regex `.replace(/>[\s\S]*/,'>')` (I like regex) (you can tell it is a regex because it is in slashes `/`...`/`)

The regular expression is `>[\s\S]*`. It will start at the beginning and move forward until it finds a `>`, then it will look for any white`s`pace or non-white`S`pace characters. (`[\s\S]`), it will look for any number of these `*`. Then it will replace `>[\s\S]*` with `>`.

Now you have the final product stored to the variable `html`. :)

(FYI, when creating new HTML snippets with jQuery (like `$('<tbody>')`), you can safely omit the end tag only if there are no children or attributes. See [jQuery: Risk of not closing tags in constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941910/jquery-risk-of-not-closing-tags-in-constructors))

Comment: Does this work? Appending a `<tr>` element directly to a `<div>` doesn't create a valid structure - are HTML parsers going to have a problem with that?

Comment: @George this did the trick. Is there anyway you could explain how you came about this answer?  I am following along in the code but if you could provide further insight I think that would be very helpful.

Comment: I am not sure if I know what you mean, but I will edit in some details.

Comment: @George - I am unfamiliar with what tr.clone() does for example and then the .replace command with the regular expression.  Again I could look all of it up but it might be helpful to others later.  Just a suggestion ;) - Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using document.getElementById, and passing the ID to jQuery is a redundant operation - that's one of the first things jQuery is for! If you know the ID of the `<tr>` element, you can just fetch it directly and use jQuery to get at the html:

```
$('#123').html()
```

Because ID's are (or should be) unique, you can safely use them to reference any element - you don't generally need to worry about starting from one of the containing elements.

I think I don't understand what you're trying to achieve properly - sorry!

Comment: I don't think this answers his question. Perhaps it should be a comment.

Comment: @Beejamin - You are correct however, I'm greatly simplifying this example to give you what I'm looking for.  The application I'm working on have duplicate IDs and I've had to jump through all sorts of hoops to set the focus :)

Comment: @Jeff, you can search on duplicate ids using `tr[id=123]` instead of `#123`. (of course that may not be the solution to your problem)